# Verification of proof: $\mathcal{T}=\bigcap_{\mathcal{T}' \supseteq \mathcal{S}} \mathcal{T}'$

Tags: general-topology

I need verification of a proof I've made for an assignment. 
The assignment goes:
Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of subsets of $X$ with $\bigcup_{A\in \mathcal{S}} A=X$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the topology on $X$, generated by $\mathcal{S}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis). Prove that
$$\mathcal{T}=\bigcap_{\mathcal{T}'\supseteq \mathcal{S}} \mathcal{T}'$$
where $\mathcal{T}'$ runs over all topologies of $X$ that contains $\mathcal{S}$. 
My proof goes: 
First, let $\bigcap_{\mathcal{T}'\supseteq \mathcal{S}} \mathcal{T'}:= \mathcal{T}_I$.
$\mathcal{T}_I \subseteq \mathcal{T}$: It is given that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, and contains $\mathcal{S}$ (since $\mathcal{T}$ is generated by $\mathcal{S}$). Futhermore, $\mathcal{T}_I$ is the intersection of all topologies of $X$ that contains $\mathcal{S}$, therefore $\mathcal{T}_I \subseteq \mathcal{T}$.

$\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_I$: Let $U=\bigcup U_i\in \mathcal{T}$, where $U_i=U_{i1} \cap U_{i2} \cap ... \cap U_{ik}$ and $U_{ij}\in \mathcal{S}$ for all $j=1,...,k$, i.e. each $U_i$ is a finite intersection of sets in $\mathcal{S}$. Notice $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_I$, and since $\mathcal{T}_I$ is closed under finite intersections and closed under arbitrary unions (because $T_{I}$ is a topology), then $U_i \in \mathcal{T}_I$ and $U \in \mathcal{T}_I$. Therefore $\mathcal{T}\subseteq \mathcal{T}_I$.

Hence, $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}_I$. 
Is my proof correct? I'm pretty confident that the first part is correct, because it is pretty clear that $\mathcal{T}_I \subseteq \mathcal{T}$, but I'm a bit insecure about the second part.

Comment: Your proof is correct. However, the whole point is the fact that $\mathcal T_I$ is a topology, so maybe you should write down a proof of this fact as part of your proof (and not use it as if it were well-known)

Comment: Also, your reaction can be improved a bit. In particular, you should separate clearly the definition of $U$ ("let $U \in \mathcal T$") from its properties ("then $U$ is a reunion of subsets $U_i$ of $X$ such that (...)").

Comment: Also, you could be more precise in your definitions of indices (for instance, you don't clearly define $k$, so we have to guess that it depends on $i$). Sloppiness in this regard can be fine, and sometimes it improves clarity, but it can also lead to confusion, so you should use it with some care (and give precise definitions by default).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! Actually, I thought about proving that $\mathcal{T}_I$ is in fact a topology, but I will definitely include it in the proof now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your ideas are correct but could be written down more succinctly as follows:

If $\mathcal{T}'$ is any topology that contains $\mathcal{S}$, then the axioms of a topology tell us that the base generated by $\mathcal{S}$ is also in $\mathcal{T}'$ and (as topologies are closed under unions) $\mathcal{T}$ is also a subset of $\mathcal{T}'$. So this proves the left to right inclusion: all the $\mathcal{T}'$ contain $\mathcal{T}$ so their intersection also does.

The other inclusion is trivial, as the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$ is *one* of the topologies that contains $\mathcal{S}$ so certainly in the intersection.